# Problem with HDMI sound on Ubuntu 17.10 running on PC with 2 x NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970

Tags: nvidia, sound, 17.04, hdmi, 17.10

I installed the proprietary Nvidia 384.90 driver and it sees both cards. The first card is connected to a Samsung “smart” monitor (unsure of model) by HDMI. There is a JVL wall speaker plugged by optical cable into the Samsung.  Up until Ubuntu 17.04, sound worked thru the HDMI.  The HDMI sound options still shows up in sound, pavucontrol, and alsamixer.

Sound still works fine when this PC is booted into Windows.

Right now, the sound coming out on 17.10 (and 17.04) is very choppy, stuttery and you cannot even make out the words.  Changing the latency helps but does not solve.   HERE IS THE ODD THING:  IF I REDUCE THE LATENCY OR INCREASE IT IN PAVUCONTROL, I GET NORMAL SOUND WHILE THE LATENCY SETTING IS BEING RESET (EITHER DIRECTION), but as soon as I stop changing it and release the  setting control (set by mouse), the choppy sound comes back.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

OUTPUT OF FOLLOWING COMMANDS AT BOTTOM:

```
obitori@atlantic:~$ cat /proc/asound/{version,cards,devices,hwdep,pcm,seq/clients}; ls -l /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/; sudo rm /etc/asound.conf; sudo rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ;sudo rm ~/.pulse-cookie; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install aptitude; sudo aptitude install paman gnome-alsamixer libasound2-plugins padevchooser libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio; sudo lshw -short;ls -lart /dev/snd; find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd ;cat /dev/sndstat; lspci -nn; lsusb; sudo which alsactl; sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp /dev/snd/* ; dpkg -S bin/slmodemd; dmesg | egrep 'EMU|probe|emu|ALSA|alsa|ac97|udi|snd|ound|irmware'; sudo /etc/init.d/sl-modem-daemon status; sudo grep model /etc/modprobe.d/* ; sudo dmidecode|egrep 'anufact|roduct|erial|elease'; lsmod | egrep 'snd|usb|midi|udio'; pacmd list-sinks; aplay -l; sudo alsa force-reload;  ubuntu-support-status ; sudo lshw -C sound  

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf5130000 irq 33
 1 [NVidia_1       ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 10
 2 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf5080000 irq 15
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 0]   : control
  3: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
  5: [ 0- 1]: digital audio playback
  6: [ 0- 2]: digital audio capture
  7: [ 0- 0]: hardware dependent
  8: [ 2]   : control
  9: [ 2- 3]: digital audio playback
 10: [ 2- 7]: digital audio playback
 11: [ 2- 8]: digital audio playback
 12: [ 1]   : control
 13: [ 2- 9]: digital audio playback
 14: [ 2- 0]: hardware dependent
 15: [ 1- 3]: digital audio playback
 16: [ 1- 7]: digital audio playback
 17: [ 1- 8]: digital audio playback
 18: [ 1- 9]: digital audio playback
 19: [ 1- 0]: hardware dependent
 33:        : timer
00-00: HDA Codec 0
02-00: HDA Codec 0
01-00: HDA Codec 0
00-00: ALC1150 Analog : ALC1150 Analog : playback 1 : capture 1
00-01: ALC1150 Digital : ALC1150 Digital : playback 1
00-02: ALC1150 Alt Analog : ALC1150 Alt Analog : capture 1
01-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
01-07: HDMI 1 : HDMI 1 : playback 1
01-08: HDMI 2 : HDMI 2 : playback 1
01-09: HDMI 3 : HDMI 3 : playback 1
02-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
02-07: HDMI 1 : HDMI 1 : playback 1
02-08: HDMI 2 : HDMI 2 : playback 1
02-09: HDMI 3 : HDMI 3 : playback 1
Client info
  cur  clients : 2
  peak clients : 2
  max  clients : 192

Client   0 : "System" [Kernel]
  Port   0 : "Timer" (Rwe-)
  Port   1 : "Announce" (R-e-)
Client  14 : "Midi Through" [Kernel]
  Port   0 : "Midi Through Port-0" (RWe-)
total 152
H/W path        Device     Class          Description
=====================================================
                           system         All Series (All)
/0                         bus            MAXIMUS VII HERO
/0/0                       memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/42                      memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/42/0                    memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1867 MHz (0
/0/42/1                    memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/42/2                    memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1867 MHz (0
/0/42/3                    memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/54                      processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00G
/0/54/55                   memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/54/56                   memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/54/57                   memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/100                     bridge         4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
/0/100/1                   bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor
/0/100/1/0                 display        GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
/0/100/1/0.1               multimedia     GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1.1                 bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor
/0/100/1.1/0               display        GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
/0/100/1.1/0.1             multimedia     GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/14                  bus            9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Contr
/0/100/14/0     usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/9              input          Optical USB Mouse
/0/100/14/0/a              input          USB Keyboard
/0/100/14/1     usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/16                  communication  9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #
/0/100/19       eno1       network        Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
/0/100/1a                  bus            9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Contr
/0/100/1a/1     usb1       bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1b                  multimedia     9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Contr
/0/100/1c                  bridge         9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Ro
/0/100/1c.3                bridge         9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Ro
/0/100/1c.3/0              storage        ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller
/0/100/1d                  bus            9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Contr
/0/100/1d/1     usb2       bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1f                  bridge         9 Series Chipset Family Z97 LPC Contro
/0/100/1f.2                storage        SATA Controller [RAID mode]
/0/100/1f.3                bus            9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controll
/0/1            scsi0      storage        
/0/1/0.0.0      /dev/sda   disk           2TB ST2000DM001-1E61
/0/1/0.0.0/1    /dev/sda1  volume         100MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2    /dev/sda2  volume         1862GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/2            scsi1      storage        
/0/2/0.0.0      /dev/sdb   disk           1TB WDC WD1001FALS-0
/0/2/0.0.0/1    /dev/sdb1  volume         29GiB Linux swap volume
/0/3            scsi2      storage        
/0/3/0.0.0      /dev/sdc   disk           250GB Samsung SSD 840
/0/3/0.0.0/1               volume         465GiB HPFS/NTFS partition
/0/4            scsi4      storage        
/0/4/0.0.0      /dev/sdd   disk           250GB Samsung SSD 840
/0/5            scsi6      storage        
/0/5/0.0.0      /dev/sde   disk           500GB Samsung SSD 850
/0/5/0.0.0/1    /dev/sde1  volume         465GiB EXT4 volume
/1                         power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
total 0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 33 Nov 11 09:42 timer
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  6 Nov 11 09:42 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  7 Nov 11 09:42 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  2 Nov 11 09:42 controlC0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 19 Nov 11 09:42 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 12 Nov 11 09:42 controlC1
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0c00] (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller [8086:0c01] (rev 06)
00:01.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller [8086:0c05] (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller [8086:8cb1]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #1 [8086:8cba]
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [8086:15a1]
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2 [8086:8cad]
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [8086:8ca0]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:8c90] (rev d0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:8c96] (rev d0)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1 [8086:8ca6]
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family Z97 LPC Controller [8086:8cc4]
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:2822]
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8ca2]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] [10de:13c2] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fbb] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] [10de:13c2] (rev a1)
02:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fbb] (rev a1)
04:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:0612] (rev 02)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

/usr/sbin/alsactl
Specified filename /dev/dsp does not exist.
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  gdm        1427 F.... pulseaudio
                     obitori    7982 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  gdm        1427 F.... pulseaudio
                     obitori    7982 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC2:  gdm        1427 F.... pulseaudio
                     obitori    7982 F.... pulseaudio
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *bin/slmodemd*
[    0.000000] Found optimal setting for mtrr clean up
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000fd870-0x000fd87f] mapped at [ffff90c0800fd870]
[    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.000000] SFI: Simple Firmware Interface v0.81 http://simplefirmware.org
[    0.056682] core: PMU erratum BJ122, BV98, HSD29 workaround disabled, HT off
[    0.056682] pci_bus 0000:00: No busn resource found for root bus, will use [bus 00-ff]
[    0.622756] platform rtc_cmos: registered platform RTC device (no PNP device found)
[    0.622756] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.622756] audit: type=2000 audit(1510411365.620:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.624327] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    0.644057] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.644076] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.664051] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.664069] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.665225] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.665243] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.665243] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    0.665243] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.665243] i8042: PNP: No PS/2 controller found.
[    0.670869] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass! (rc=-19)
[    0.671073] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    0.673248] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    1.127881] usb 3-9: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c016
[    1.388381] usb 3-10: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c31c
[    7.337377] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    7.521102] audit: type=1400 audit(1510411373.367:2): apparmor="STATUS" 

[    7.551510] snd_hda_intel: unknown parameter 'vid' ignored
[    7.551511] snd_hda_intel: unknown parameter 'pid' ignored
[    7.551564] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: can't find IRQ for PCI INT A; probably buggy MP table
[    7.551566] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: Force to non-snoop mode by module option
[    7.551916] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: can't find IRQ for PCI INT B; probably buggy MP table
[    7.551918] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    7.551921] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    7.551921] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Force to non-snoop mode by module option
[    7.551930] snd_hda_intel 0000:02:00.1: can't find IRQ for PCI INT B; probably buggy MP table
[    7.551932] snd_hda_intel 0000:02:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    7.551933] snd_hda_intel 0000:02:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    7.551934] snd_hda_intel 0000:02:00.1: Force to non-snoop mode by module option
[    7.664965] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: ALC1150: SKU not ready 0x00000000
[    7.665477] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC1150: line_outs=4 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x17/0x0) type:line
[    7.665478] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    7.665479] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    7.665479] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    7.665479] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[    7.665480] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    7.665481] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[    7.665481] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[    7.665482] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
[    7.721209] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input6
[    7.721233] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[    7.721253] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[    7.721271] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[    7.721290] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[    7.721310] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[    7.721328] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[    7.721346] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[    7.878316] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    7.878317] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    7.878317] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
               drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
[   10.581931] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x000f0001
[   10.581937] snd_hda_intel 0000:02:00.1: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x000f0001
[   11.686219] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.1/sound/card2/input14
[   11.686280] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.1/sound/card2/input15
[   11.686330] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.1/sound/card2/input16
[   11.686373] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input18
[   11.686389] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.1/sound/card2/input17
[   11.686444] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input19
[   11.686472] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input20
[   11.686504] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input21
[   21.868941] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #0. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.
sudo: /etc/init.d/sl-modem-daemon: command not found
    Release Date: 07/16/2014
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
    Manufacturer: ASUS
    Product Name: All Series
    Serial Number: System Serial Number
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: MAXIMUS VII HERO
    Serial Number: 140932637402584
    Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Manufacturer: 0420
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Manufacturer: 0420
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Manufacturer: Intel
    Serial Number: Not Specified

snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  3 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  2
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  12
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  35 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid

2 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9050
    volume: front-left: 316 /   0% / -139.01 dB,   front-right: 316 /   0% / -139.01 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 100.14 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 1"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 1"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "7"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 10"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0fbb"
        device.product.name = "GM204 High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "hdmi:1,1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "17664"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "2944"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo-extra1"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
        device.description = "GM204 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU 71 HDMI/DP"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10de0071,38422977,00100100"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "SAMSUNG
     "
    active port: <hdmi-output-1>
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9958
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 99.95 ms
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC1150 Digital"
        alsa.id = "ALC1150 Digital"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "1"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf5130000 irq 33"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8ca0"
        device.product.name = "9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "iec958:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "17632"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "4408"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC1150"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0900,10438602,00100001"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

    active port: <iec958-stereo-output>

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
  *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:10 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:15 memory:f5080000-f5083fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:f5130000-f5133fff
```

Comment: What is the output from: `setpci -vD -s 01:00.0 0x488.l=0x2000000:0x2000000`?